# Can't create table "Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed" SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new into SQL and I'm having a little problem with my SQL code. I have been searching a lot about this kind of error but I couldn't find any answer that suits for my problem. Here's the code example.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `PracticaER`;
USE `PracticaER`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Banco;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cuenta;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Usuario;

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
id_usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DNI VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
usuario VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Contrasena VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE Cuenta (
CIF_Banco VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
num_cuenta INT NOT NULL,
balance FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
fecha_apertura VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DNI VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (num_cuenta),
FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES Usuario(DNI)
);

CREATE TABLE Banco (
CIF VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
cod_oficial INT NOT NULL,
pais VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CIF),
FOREIGN KEY (CIF) REFERENCES Cuenta(CIF_Banco)
);
```

When I execute MySQL, this is the error. Basically it can't create the table "Banco".

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `practicaer`.`banco` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference a column in the `Cuenta` table that is not UNIQUE or the PRIMARY KEY of that table. MySQL allows that to be done, if you add an index to the column on that table (as in Giorgos Betsos's answer), but recommends against it:

> Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed
>   for performance reasons. However, the system does not enforce a
>   requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT
>   NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys
>   that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as
>   UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that
>   reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

Either make `CIF_Banco` the PK of the `Cuenta` table, or make it a UNIQUE index, to have both the CREATE TABLE statement execute, and for the constraint itself to work in a predictable way.

Add this line to the `Cuenta` table's CREATE statement:

```
UNIQUE INDEX IDX_CIF(CIF_Banco)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

So in order to be able to create the foreign key you have to add this line to the `CREATE TABLE` statement of table `Cuenta`:

```
INDEX IDX_CIF(CIF_Banco)
```

[**Working Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbe1b)

Comment: Although correct in syntax, the results may not work as desired. See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It's because of the constraints in the banco table.
have a closer look to this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (CIF) REFERENCES Cuenta(CIF_Banco)
```

You are referencing to the same CIF.

Note that all foreign key constraint must always consist of all PK columns.